# Select earliest date for each Contact

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following query, it should pull just the earliest date for each contact, but it's pulling all available dates. I have reviewed multiple threads here but wasn't able to solve it. 
This is using SQL Server 2005.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.SubscriberKey, MIN(o.EventDate) as OpenDate
FROM _Open o 
INNER JOIN _Job j
    ON o.JobID = j.JobID
GROUP BY o.SubscriberKey, o.EventDate
```

Currently, I am getting results like this:

```
Subscriber 1  17 July 2019 06:04
Subscriber 1  17 July 2019 06:05
Subscriber 1  18 July 2019 04:29
Subscriber 2  18 July 2019 07:04
Subscriber 2  18 July 2019 07:21
Subscriber 2  24 July 2019 05:40
```

And what I would like to achieve:

```
Subscriber 1  17 July 2019 06:04
Subscriber 2  18 July 2019 07:04
```

Comment: Something against July 24th?

Comment: You rarely never need to combine GROUP BY with SELECT DISTINCT!

Comment: remove the DISTINCT
and stop grouping on o.EventDate as this is stopping the MIN function from doing anything

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Just remove the `o.EventDate` from the query and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     --you dont want to have a DISTINCT here, you are doing a GROUP BY so its not needed 
    --DISTINCT
    o.SubscriberKey
    , MIN(o.EventDate) as OpenDate
FROM _Open o 
    --Join is not referenced. Thanks @Gordon Linoff
    --INNER JOIN _Job j
    --    ON o.JobID = j.JobID
GROUP BY
    o.SubscriberKey
    --dont group on Event date, this is stopping the MIN function from aggregating the rows.
    --, o.EventDate
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `JOIN` for this.  And you need to fix the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT o.SubscriberKey, MIN(o.EventDate) as OpenDate
FROM _Open o 
GROUP BY o.SubscriberKey;
```

You only need the `JOIN` if it is filtering results, but I doubt that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to `group by SubscriberKey` and aggregate on `EventDate`. 
Also you are joining `_Job` but you don't use it. 
Unless you only want to get the minimum `EventDate` of the matching rows of the tables there is no need for this join:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, MIN(EventDate) as OpenDate
FROM _Open 
GROUP BY SubscriberKey
```